# How do i create a url and page for every new page

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm currently creating a forum application from scratch but i'm stuck. I want to know how  forum and blog softwares are able to create a page for each new post without generating a physical file. I've searched in all the folders but can't find a single file. It means it has something to do with the database. I also want it to be seen by search engines. How can that be done?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).  That will do what you are looking for.

Another good resource is [this website](http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/) that goes over some examples.